# rpcbind.service fails to start in RHEL 7.4 after disabling IPv6

Tags: rhel

I am disabling ipv6 via **sysctl** as follows:

```
echo net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1 > /etc/sysctl.d/ipv6.conf
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/ipv6.conf
```

and I did run dracut to recreate initramfs as suggested in the following link https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2798411 and did everything as said

```
dracut -v -f
```

and this is the state of rpcbind.* process

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep rpcbind
rpcbind.service                               indirect
rpcbind.socket                                enabled
rpcbind.target                                static
```

on reboot, I could see only rpcbind.socket has successfully started and rpcbind.service is in dead state

```
systemctl status rpcbind.socket
● rpcbind.socket - RPCbind Server Activation Socket
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (listening) since Thu 2018-02-15 11:25:09 GMT; 26min ago
   Listen: /var/run/rpcbind.sock (Stream)
           0.0.0.0:111 (Stream)

Feb 15 11:25:09 seliics01979 systemd[1]: Listening on RPCbind Server Activation Socket.
Feb 15 11:25:09 seliics01979 systemd[1]: Starting RPCbind Server Activation Socket.

 systemctl status rpcbind.service
● rpcbind.service - RPC bind service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I am puzzled to see that the rpcbind.service is still not starting up. However, manual start of rpcbind.service works fine. This happens in both VM and HP Gen9 hardware. Help required.

```
cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.service
[Unit]
Description=RPC bind service
Requires=rpcbind.socket
After=systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/rpcbind
ExecStart=/sbin/rpcbind -w $RPCBIND_ARGS

[Install]
Also=rpcbind.socket


cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.target

[Unit]
Description=RPC Port Mapper
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
RefuseManualStart=true


cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.socket
[Unit]
Description=RPCbind Server Activation Socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/rpcbind.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Comment: Start the command by hand to see if it gives  a more informative error; I also had problems with `xinetd`, `snmpd` and `postfix` (in Debian)

Comment: Manual start of rpcbind.service is successful, but not persisting across reboot

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by removing the ::1 localhost address from /etc/hosts.  It seems somehow this also triggers the behavior